# Run multiple/all sql files and show error log file

Tags: c#, sql, logging

How to run all SQL files in a directory and display the error of the script you execute if there is an error, how will you log or record the error upon running?

Comment: how are you running one sql file in a directory?  please provide more context.  as it stands your question is way to broad.

Comment: By using batch file i think yet i want/need to show how to log the error (if there is an error) on the executed script

Comment: Ok, what OS are you using?  The answer is not the same in Unix and DOS.  Can you show us the content of your batch file?  How do you expect us to answer if you don't?

Comment: Im using Windows i send the link below/on my answer to my question. please see it. Btw. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *rough* function to execute the SQL files in a directory, minus validation and maybe a little more separation. In real life I'd probably separate this out - one function to find the files, another to execute a collection of files.

```
    public void ExecuteSqlFilesInDirectory(string path, string connectionString)
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = directory.GetFiles("*.sql");
        if (!files.Any()) return;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var sql = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Logging is a whole separate question which I won't try to answer in the same context as this.

Question - does the order of execution matter? If so, how will the order be indicated so that the function knows the sequence?

Also, if there is an error do they all need to be rolled back?

Comment: The order of execution also matters according to the sql file you import/insert. Hmmm about the sequence gobalakrishnan is right about using bat. If there is or are error(s) i want to show the message in a log file or textpad or any way to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use batch file to run all the scripts in one click.

Put all your stored procedure's and Views filenames as stated below and save it in .bat extension. Just click on batch file which will run all at once where you can watch for errors as well.

Example:

```
set DBName=myDB
set DBServer="127.0.0.1\SQLInstance"
REM Product List Stored Procedures 
osql -E -i GetList.sql -d %DBNAME% -S %DBServer% -n
osql -E -i InsertProduct.sql -d %DBNAME% -S %DBServer% -n
osql -E -i UpdateProduct.sql -d %DBNAME% -S %DBServer% -n
osql -E -i DeleteProduct.sql -d %DBNAME% -S %DBServer% -n
pause
```

Comment: Thanks i also thought about that, yet how about if there are errors. How to show it in a log file or notepad or any way to show the error on the executed script.?

Comment: After all the files have been executed, you can review the errors on same command prompt window. You can also save this by copying the whole text. This will capture the error's as well. You can include 'pause' wherever you want. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question. I found this useful I just want to share it.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1543/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-multiple-sql-server-scripts/
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sqlcmd+mode/129764/

The only thing i need is to log an error showing the SQL file followed by the error compiled in the Notepad.